# ClassCastException while returning generic type

Tags: java, spring, clean-architecture, vavr

I'm writing Spring application and I want to divide it into several layers to separate domain from framework totally.

So, my domain methods are returning vavr's `Either<Error, T>` and my controllers are using simple resolver for all of those methods.

```
  <T> ResponseEntity resolve(Either<Error, T> either) {
        return either
           .map(this::successResponse)
           .getOrElseGet(this::failureResponse);
  }

  private ResponseEntity<Object> successResponse(Object obj) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.toDto(obj), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

The problem is, I don't want to return my domain entities from controllers, so I wrote generic mapper, which will translate each domain object to its dto with single method.

```
 public <T, Y> Y toDto(T domainObject) {        
     if(domainObject instanceof Reservation) {
         return (Y) reservationMapper.toDto((Reservation)domainObject);
     }
     return null;
 }
```

`Reservation` and `ReservationMapper` are here concrete implementations of one domain, `if` can be ofcourse replaced with better solution, but that's not the case.

The case is, it isn't working. It throws

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.johndoe.reservationsystem.adapter.dto.ReservationDto cannot be
>   cast to class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap

I found workaround which is creating empty abstract class `Dto`, make all my dto classes extend this, and just return `Dto` instead of `Y` in `toDto` method. The point is, I don't really like it and I'd like to find better solution.

Probably its not necessary, but here is implementation of `ReservationMapper`

```
class ReservationMapper {
    ReservationDto toDto(Reservation reservation) {
        return ReservationDto.builder()
                .id(reservation.getId())
                .ownerId(reservation.getOwnerId())
                .reservedObjectId(reservation.getReservedObjectId())
                .title(reservation.getTitle())
                .description(reservation.getDescription())
                .startDate(reservation.getStartDate())
                .endDate(reservation.getEndDate())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you are using vavr seems irrelevant to the problem you are facing. If you agree that is the case, you could simplify your question by eliminating unnecessary details like like that. Also, complete stack traces are important to determine which part of the code is trying to do the cast and thus causing your error.

Comment: `return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.toDto(obj), HttpStatus.OK);` is causing error

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature

```
public <T, Y> Y toDto(T domainObject)
```

is causing the problem, because, in the context of your invocation

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.toDto(obj), HttpStatus.OK)
```

is interpreted as if it's able to return a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` to conform to the constructor

```
public ResponseEntity(MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus status)
```

See javadoc: [`ResponseEntity(MultiValueMap<String, String>, HttpStatus)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ResponseEntity-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-)

By modifying your `toDto` method to make it explicit that it's definitely not returning a `MultiValueMap` you can work around this problem. For example, just specifying:

```
public Object toDto(Object domainObject)
```

for the conversion method will probably do it. Or you could constrain your generic arguments so as to make it explicit that it cannot return an instance of an arbitrary type based on the type inference context its invocation currently is.